# R XML2Obs Could not resolve host

Tags: xml, r

I have the following code.

```
#Autonomous pension fund assets
file <- "http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/UN_DEN/AUS+USA+OECD/OECD?startTime=1960&endTime=2012"
obs <- XML2Obs(file)
```

I got it from here: http://stronginstruments.com/2014/03/02/reading-oecd-stat-into-r/
I do not intend to break copyright.

The code fails and says the following:

```
> obs <- XML2Obs(file)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: ; No data record of requested type
```

I've tried setInternet2(T) and allowed Rstudio as well as Rx64 through my firewall but it still gives the same error. On another try (with a new fresh url from OECD site), the "Could not resolve host" was gone and only "No data record of requested type" was there.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried going to that URL but I get an application error. It simply appears that that specific resource is no longer available. Perhaps the API has changed since that article was written.

Comment: Robert, I wrote that article. I often have issues fetching the data from the OECD. I think they have a pretty serious issue on their end... You could try an example SDMX from this website to see if it works - http://stat.abs.gov.au/

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for responding and for writing the code. Oddly enough, this data works. Considering this does not work at the moment, I'm trying the JSON method but I'm fairly new to it. If I figured it out, I'll add it here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For reading OECD data provided in SDMX format, i recommend you to look to [rsdmx](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx), a package that allows to read SDMX data and metadata. The package is available in CRAN repository.

You just have to do this:

```
require(rsdmx)
url = "http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/UN_DEN/AUS+USA+OECD/OECD?startTime=1960&endTime=2012"
sdmxObj = readSDMX(url)
df = as.data.frame(url)
```

and that's it! You can check the [wiki](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/wiki) for mor examples and information about the package. Hope this helps.